# Extract datasheet information via regex

Tags: regex, extract

I want to extract information like register name, adress, enumarations from a datasheet using regex. I found the wonderful website regexr.com, which helps in most cases but not with this problem (to complex?).

http://regexr.com/4jeug

I tried to do a few groups and pull out a list (CSV). But everytime I put in more than one groups I stuck. I need something like
(A2B_????) blablablablab Address: (0x??) blablablalbalb "16 digits" ([A-Z]+)

I would expect

```
A2B_NODEADR, 0x01, BRCST, NODE, PERI
A2B_VENDOR, 0x0A, VENDOR
A2B_PRODUCT, 0x03, PRODUCT
```

Comment: Can you share the input text in your question?

Comment: The JS flavor of regex does not make it easy to work with newlines so you need to switch it to PCRE and make use of the `/s` modifier. See https://regexr.com/4jf0r. Do note that all programming languages tend to build functional luxuries into their regex processing so if you are using a specific language then it could be helpful to tell us what that is.

Comment: Something like https://regex101.com/r/NvxDwo/1?

Comment: ok now next level.. how can i ensure that only the first unique Register Name is found? So in this example the "A2B_NODEADR" is found twice, because it's in the following caption. So i would say only if a "The" precedes  and there is no "." following. I tried to add (?!\.) but doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

> So i would say only if a "The" precedes and there is no "." following. I tried to add (?!.) but doesn't help.

This sounds like you already figured out the pattern for *if a "The" precedes*: `(?<=The )`. The reason why *(?!.) but doesn't help* is that this just causes the preceding `(A2B_[A-Z]+)` to match the name without the last letter, thus fulfilling the *no "." following*. To avoid this, we can specify that also no letter may follow; we don't even need lookahead for that: `(A2B_[A-Z]+)[^A-Z.]`.

https://regexr.com/4jit2